# Jquery Autocomplete not displaying as it should

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, themes

I have a JQuery autocomplete box, however its not working as it should.  The search is working correctly, but when I display the results (inside the autocomplete box), I cannot see the text, just a horizontal blue slider which is very thin, and no text.

I am using the JQuery Theme Redmond, and have the following js calls :-

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<link href="Content/Redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
```

and the JQuery is as follows :-

```
        //reports Navbar AutoComplete
    $("#reports-textSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Dashboard.aspx/FetchReports",
                data: "{'reportName':'" + document.getElementById('reports-textSearch').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                    var val = $("#reports-textSearch").val();
                    //__doPostBack('div#UPMainMenu', val);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: '', results: function () {
            }
        }

    });
```

and the HTML is as follows:-

```
  <div id="navbar-reportsSearch">
      <div class="navbar-reportsAutoSearchBar">
          <input id="reports-textSearch"   />
      </div>
  </div>
```

I also added some styling to the autocomplete but nothing seemed to be working :-

```
#reports-textSearch {
width: 235px;
z-index: 100; 
position: relative
}


#reports-textSearch > li {
border: #000000;

}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data you're getting back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<input id="reports-textSearch"   />
```

with

```
<input type="text" id="reports-textSearch"   />
```

you need to mention the type of input also

Comment: I already had it on type="text" and removed it before.  I tried again but still problematic

Comment: and have you add any style for autocomplete background and color..??

Comment: no I have not, isn't that in the JqueryUI  Stylesheet I downloaded?  How to add that?

Comment: link it to your page as you linked the stylesheet

Comment: I did, did not work though.  I have decided to do it manually now without any autosearchcomplete